# How can I open the Stellaris Console?

Tags: linux, stellaris

I was trying to tweak my Stellaris Graphics for better performance using a [reddit tutorial](https://www.reddit.com/r/Stellaris/comments/4im9q2/how_i_improved_my_framerate_by_40_fps/). But I wasn't able to open the Stellaris console by using the described keys. Also I tried all combinations mentioned in the [corresponding wiki page](http://www.stellariswiki.com/Console_commands).

I think that I can't open the console is caused by the fact that my OS, linux, uses the alt-key as a system key and that I need to use an alt combination.

Is there maybe a way to open the console by changing the keyboard layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Linux Ubuntu 14.04 and I use the key left of number one, under <kbd>Esc</kbd>. The tilde key: <kbd>~</kbd>

Is your keyboard in German?

I'm asking because, for me, it wasn't working at first since my keyboard is in French, but it did after I changed the language to English.